# No puedo acceder a la consola de jboss Wilfly

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Espero estén muy bien, los pondre un poco en contexto:

Realice la instalación de wildfly sobre un servidor Oracle Linux, Segui todos los pasos, todo funciono bien, pude ingresar normalmente, y muy bien: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, cuando intento acceder a la consola, me aparece esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Configure todo los datos bien. Inicio servicio y los puertos escuchan:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cambie al puerto 9991 por si eso me presentaba problema pero claramente no, y esta escuchando en estos momentos tambien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, le agradecería demasiado.

Comment: ¿172.27.11.236 es tu misma máquina u otra? ¿Estás seguro que no hay ningún firewall por enmedio?

Comment: Desde otra ... Voy a validar este tema.

Comment: Si tienes ssh en esa máquina, puedes hacer "wget http://127.27.11.236:9991/console" a ver si te conecta